# Using a java.nio.file.Path instance and a string to navigate to a sub-path

Tags: java, nio2

How can I use a `java.nio.file.Path` object to navigate to a sub-path?

I'd have thought that something like `path = path.subFolder(string)` would work where `string` specifies a sub-folder relative to the initial `path`.

But there doesn't seem to be such a method available.

Before "I go in and out of a string", I'd like to check if I've missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`Path.resolve(other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.lang.String-).

Quoting its Javadoc:

> For example, suppose that the name separator is `"/"` and a path represents `"foo/bar"`, then invoking this method with the path string `"gus"` will result in the Path `"foo/bar/gus"`.

Sample code:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/foo/bar");
Path subFolder = path.resolve("gus"); // represents the path "/foo/bar/gus"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `#get()` utility method in the `java.nio.file.Paths` class:

```
Paths.get(String first, String... more)
```

This is documented as:

> Converts a path string, or a sequence of strings that when joined form a path string, to a Path.